# Googles camera2video example crashes (low end device)

Tags: android, android-camera2

When I stop recording on a Alcatel oneTouch XL that i got from metropcs store for basically free it crashes. Here is the logcat https://jpst.it/Tc6c . I tried it on my nexus 6 and pixel. Nexus 6 has different issue and pixel works just fine neither crash though. The Alcatel is running 5.1.1. Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Does the device indeed have an Adreno? Some low end devices use MediaTek processors, so it might just be compiled for the wrong device. The other thing I would check is the OpenGL version. In any event, I don't think there is going to be an easy fix here. If it is a really cheap device then there is probably little inventive for the manufacturer to issue a patch if it is indeed a bug.

Edit:

After some research it appears that the Alcatel phone has a 32 bit processor, while the others are Arm 64. It seems that the apk you have was compiled only for the 64 bit architecture (I am guessing this based on the fact that it works on the pixel). I would suggest you try downloading the original apk from the play store, which should ensure that the apk you get is for the correct device.

Comment: this is all i know about this phone... http://www.gsmarena.com/alcatel_fierce_xl-7720.php Im going to send the apk to my bro with samsung phone and see how it works.

Comment: Oh you made it sound like this was a super cheap phone. Looks totally legit. But from your comment, it sounds like you're trying to install an apk directly, and not by going through the Google Play store. If that is indeed the case, then it is probably the case that your APK was compiled for a different device. Especially when the app has native components, you need to be very careful that you have the APK specifically compiled for your processor. Since the error indicates indicates a native error, it could be that you do not have the correct version of the app for your device.

Comment: I did a little digging. The Alcatel phone you have seems to have a 32 bit processor, while the other phones are arm 64. I would guess that that is almost definitely the issue.